# Displaying Multiple Texts from Database

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sqlite

Hey guys Android noob here,

I am trying to develop an application that only shows some content (text only) and you can mark as favorite some of these content.

When I click to favorite button, I want to display the favorited content in one .xml file. So I can display ONE text in one page at a time, how can I display multiple texts in a row.

Here is the template of .xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/string_fav1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/string_deneme"
    android:textColor="@color/pinky_black"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/string_fav2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/string_fav1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/string_deneme"
    android:textColor="@color/pinky_black"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/string_fav3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/string_fav2"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/string_deneme"
    android:textColor="@color/pinky_black"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:typeface="serif" />
```

These items have been displayed in static way. So these must be items from database.

Thank you for answering. I hope I explained well enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LinearLayout` for that,putting those 3 **textboxes** in a row like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/txtElement"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24px">
    </TextView>
      <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/txtElement2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24px">
    </TextView>
      <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/txtElement3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24px">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Or,
Alternatively use `RelativeLayout` like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="TextView 1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="TextView 2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="TextView 3" />
```